# Python Subtract integers in List to return a value

Tags: python, list, element

I would like to take a large file like this in Python 2.7:

```
123 456 GTHGGGTH
223 567 FGRTHSYS
12933 4656832 GJWSOOOSKKSSJ
.....
```

and I want to read in the file line by line, disregard the third element, and subtract the second element in each line by the first element. Thus line 1 above would return 333.

I have tried this so far:

```
def deleteLast(list):      
    NewL = list.pop()        
    return NewL

f = open(file_name, 'r')
line = f.readline()
while line:
    L = line.split()
    L2 = deleteLast(L)
    L3 = [int(number) for number in L2]
    Length = L3[1]-L3[0]
    print Length
f.close()
```

But, when I try this the compiler says:

```
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T'
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It is clear, concise, and accurately describes the problem and what was tried.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `list.pop()` is returning the "popped off" item, it doesn't return the list again.

Instead of this `deleteLast` function you have written, it would be better just to use a slice like this:

`L2 = line.split()[0:2]`

You are going to run into another problem later because your while loop isn't advancing at all.  Consider using a for loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
In [8]: with open("abc") as f:     #always use with statement when handling files
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         x,y=map(int,line.split()[:2])
   ...:         print y-x
   ...:         
333
344
4643899
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This code worked very well. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        rowData = line.split()
        left, right = map(int, rowData[:2])
        length = right - left
        print length
```

Or:

```
from operator import sub

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print sub(*map(int, line.split()[:2])[::-1])
```

Comment: I think `sub` is an overkill for just two operands.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is just an option and nothing more, Op can simply read about it and learn about operator module

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(file_name, 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
     x, y = line.split(' ')[:2]
     print int(y) - int(x)
```